# How can I solve the SSL certificate and error response code 400 problem in JMeter?

Tags: java, proxy, jmeter, ssl-certificate, performance-testing

I am unable to record the script using the Correlation recorder in the JMeter. As soon as I open the browser for recording, I get an error message stating "Problem with SSL certificate for URL" and Error response code 400.

I ensured the proxy setting was correct. I checked the CA certificate validity and it is imported properly. What am I missing? The screenshot below shows the error in the console as soon as I launch the browser for recording.

--> [**error screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CBPt.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to "solve" here? I think you should rather exclude any requests to URLs containing `mozilla` from the recording scope than trying to fix SSL issue with [Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/) services (unless you're a Mozilla employee which does performance testing of these services). The setting lives under "Requests Filtering" tab of the [HTTPS(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

[image]

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates